# Passing PSCustomObject as a global Variable in Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am creating a build pipeline (YAML) with some "Powershell" task in it in which all are not inline scripts. I need to have a PSCustomObject that can be passed as a global variable (this param should be accessible across the pipeline). For example, it needs to be used like this. $myPSObject.value1 in first task, $myPSObject.value2 in second task etc. Is it possible?

Any leads would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is definitely not possible, what you can do, however, is cast it to json (compressed would, probably, make more sense) and then in your steps read it and cast it back to an object and work with it like you normally would. You'd need to use azure devops build variable for that, not powershell variable

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I myself found another way to accomplish what I have described above. I have iterated through the json file and created ##vso[task.setvariable=key]value for each key value pairs so that these are accessible across the pipeline.